# Discord.js Slash Commands saying missing access even though I have "Use slash commands" scope on

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to make a bot that uses slash commands and the code looks like this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const {token} = require("./config.json")

const client = new Discord.Client()
const guildId = "798268649613033532"

const getApp = (guildId) => {
    const app = client.api.applications(client.user.id)
    if (guildId) {
        app.guilds(guildId)
    }
    return app
}

client.once("ready", async () => {
    console.log("Ready!")

    try {
        const commands = getApp(guildId).commands.get()
        console.log(commands)
        
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})

client.login(token)
```

but in the console it says: "Promise {  }
(node:1848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Access"

I know I have use slash commands permission/scope on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when you invite the bot, the scope is on. Also, use slash commands is a permission, not a scope. You need at least these 2 boxes checked when you copy the link.
[image: bot and application.commands boxes checked]

Comment: You answered my question but now its telling me Promise { <Pending> }

Comment: What is saying that?

Comment: What are you console logging?

Comment: Which error? I want to know what variable it is

Comment: Wait, I think post commands is a Promise, to console log it, put await, same with get, try that tell me what happens